# IE8 JavaScript Popup "Stackoverflow at line 3"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, stack-overflow

I am developing a web-application for IE8.

The Problem is: My JavaScript/JQuery Code shows a popup "Stackoverflow at line 3":

```
$(new Array(
    new Array(/\xE4/g, "&auml;"), //ä
    new Array(/\xF6/g, "&ouml;"), //ö
    new Array(/\xFC/g, "&uuml;"), //ü
    new Array(/\xC4/g, "&Auml;"), //Ä
    new Array(/\xD6/g, "&Ouml;"), //Ö
    new Array(/\xDC/g, "&Uuml;")  //Ü
)).each(function(){
    $("textarea[name=remarks]").val($("textarea[name=remarks]").val().replace(this[0], this[1]));
    $("input[name=firstname]").val($("input[name=firstname]").val().replace(this[0], this[1]));
    $("input[name=lastname]").val($("input[name=lastname]").val().replace(this[0], this[1]));
    alert("1"); //after popup "1" ==> stackoverflow popup appears...
});
alert("2"); //is not executed
```

This error does only appear in IE8, in no other browsers, not in IE 10, nor in its Compatibility mode...

Does anyone has a solution in mind?
As far as I know there also are no recursions, right?

edit:
The error message doesn't appear after the first loop. It appears aktually after the 6th "1"-popup...

Comment: Does the console say anything more, or is it just that popup error?

Comment: That code is very very inefficient. You keep looking up and writing to the DOM. I am not surprised IE is freaking out.

Comment: Offtopic but nevertheless. Your solution seems to be really inefficient since you are doing multiple DOM manipulations and lookups while you only need 3 of them. `$('textarea[name=remarks], input[name=firstname], input[name=lastname]').each(function(){var $this = $(this), val = $this.val(); val = val.replace(/(\xE4|\xF6|\xFC|\xC4|\xD6|\xDC)/g, function($1){return '&' + {'\xE4': 'a', ...}[$1] + 'uml;' }); $this.val(val)});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really ashamed...

First I noticed that the error consisted even when I deleted the code which I thought was the cause.

Then I found the real source of the error:
My application uses a jQuery plugin which creates a watermark to inputs & textareas.

A few weeks ago i changed something in it as a bugfix - and also wrote something like this:

```
$(...).submit(function(){
  ...
  $(...).submit();
  ...
});
```

==> nice recursion... >_<

@Yury Tarabanko
Thank you for that code snippet.